# Update all values in Primary Key column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains a primary key where the value is an ID number ranging from 1-4 digits at the moment. For example:

1. 100
2. 101
3. 102
4. 103

I would now like to add the same text at the beginning of each value, whilst still keeping the rest of the ID. So for example, this is how I would like my primary keys to now show:

1. IN100
2. IN101
3. IN102
4. IN104

Could someone please describe how to do this? Any searches I have found don't seem to relate to adding text at the beginning of the value whilst keeping the rest of it the same.

Comment: What is the type of your primary key column?

Comment: But why? Aren't those integer id's just fine?`

Comment: Add 11 and 12345 to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: The type of column is currently 'Float'. And I need these changing as I will be adding in new rows of data from a different source where the new PK values could be duplicated. Therefore I want to rename the current ones as 'IN101' and the new ones will be added as 'OUT101'.

Comment: why not use a computed column or even a view outputing a new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT()` or `+` solves your problem.  It sounds like you want a new id in the table.  If so, you can alter the table:

```
alter table t add newid as ('IN' + convert(varchar(255), id));
```

This will allow you to query on the new id in any query that references the table.

You can actually update the id in place by doing:

```
alter table t alter column id varchar(255);

update t
    set id =  'IN' + convert(varchar(255), id);
```

Note that this might mess up foreign key references.

However, I think it might be better to have a "source" column as a *separate* column in the table as well as encoding it in the `id`.  In other words, perhaps you should ask another question about your *problem* and see if other solutions are a better fit.

Comment: I would suggest to add something like `RIGHT(CONCAT('000',CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4))), 4)`in order to get same length on all new IDs...

Comment: @Tyron78 . . . Except that the OP specifies that the id could have 1 to 4 characters, and the example is clearly *not* left padded.

Comment: Yes, you are right - sorry. But: Wasn't ment as correction of your answer but as "add-on" to it. Guess because I'm used to padding key columns when it comes to char values.

Comment: This is the one, thank you. Made me realise that I would be better off with this new column as the PK rather than updating the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE NewTable
(
SNo INT,
ID VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO NewTable(SNo,ID)
    SELECT SNo,'IN'+CONVERT(varchar(10),ID)  FROM OldTable

--Finally drop your existing Old table 

DROP TABLE OldTable
```